# Count the number of comments in a C program

Tags: c, file, file-io, comments, enumeration

I've started studying C in the university. The professor gave us a task - to write a program that counts the number of comments in an another C program. We still haven't talked about operating with files. I found a similar solution - [C Program to count comment lines (// and /* */)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845074/c-program-to-count-comment-lines-and) . Modified it a bit and it actually works but I can't understand the `enum` stuff. Tried to rewrite it without enumerations but with no success (cuz we have to explain how to program works). My question is - is there a way to solve it without enumerations?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

FILE *fp;
int c, i=0;
char ch;
char path[150];

unsigned int chars  = 0;
unsigned int multi  = 0;
unsigned int single = 0;

enum states { TEXT, 
    SAW_SLASH, 
    SAW_STAR, 
    SINGLE_COMMENT, 
    MULTI_COMMENT } state = TEXT;

printf("Write file's path. Separate the folders with TWO back slashes (\\)\n");
scanf("%s", &path);

fp = fopen(path, "r");
if ( !fp )
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s\n", argv[1] );
}
else {
    while((c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF){

    switch( state ) {
        case TEXT :
        switch( c )
        {
            case '/'  : state = SAW_SLASH; break;
            default   : break;
        }
        break;
        case SAW_SLASH :
            switch( c )
            {
              case '/'  : 
                  printf("case SLASH case / \n");
                  state = SINGLE_COMMENT; 
                  break;
              case '*'  : 
                  printf("case SLASH case * \n");
                  state = MULTI_COMMENT; 
                  break;
              default   : 
                  state = TEXT; 
                  break;
            }
            break;
        case SAW_STAR :
            switch( c )
            {
                case '/'  : 
                    printf("case STAR case / \n");
                    state = TEXT; 
                    multi++; 
                    break;
                case '*'  : 
                    break;
                case '\n' : 
                    printf("case SLASH case 'NEW LINE' \n");
                    multi++; // fall through
                default   : 
                    state = MULTI_COMMENT; 
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case SINGLE_COMMENT :
            switch( c )
            {
              case '\n' : 
                  printf("case SINGLE case NEW LINE \n");
                  state = TEXT; 
                  single++; // fall through
              default   : 
                  break;
            }
            break;
        case MULTI_COMMENT :
            switch( c )
            {
              case '*'  : 
                  printf("case MULTI case * \n");
                  state = SAW_STAR; 
                  break;
              case '\n' : 
                break;
              default   : 
                  break;
            }
            break;

        default: // NOT REACHABLE
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf( "File                 : %s\n", argv[1] );
    printf( "Single-comment: %8u\n", single );
    printf( "Multi-comment: %8u\n", multi );

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't read it carefully but enums really have nothing to do with it. I don't necessarily think you're properly doing the assignment, but using #define for the states should work just the same. Also, are you sure you don't have to make it not comments in strings? (It looks like this would count "// not a comment" as a comment).

Comment: @Lupe Tested the code and works fine. But i'm trying to find an alternative way to do it.

Comment: @Lupe PS: Actually you are write. "// not a comment" is considered a comment. Anyway, still gotta find an alternative.

Comment: It is not trivial: the string literal may contain an escaped `\"` which does *not* mark the end of the string. Just as a comment may contain `"`.

Comment: This is written using a pattern called "State machine". The "enum stuff" is just a symbolic names for the states.

Comment: @Alex Like I said, the enums don't matter. Use #defines or C-style constants if you prefer, but they'd just be a somewhat more confusing version of the enums. Do you have to exclude comments in strings? I doubt you'd get an assignment with that sort of requirement before learning how to use enums, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Your code includes `"… Separate the folders with TWO back slashes (\\)…"`. Note that when you read a string from the terminal, you do not need to double up the backslashes; that is only a problem in C source code.  Note that your message prints just one backslash; that may have been what you intended, but if you intended to print two, you need to write ``\\\\`` to embed two adjacent backslashes in the output string.

Comment: @Lupe The file which is going to be read shouldn't compulsory work. Actually just for the test i'm reading a PHP file. The assignment says: "Write a C program which reads another C program and counts the number of the comments in it." So the program which is going to be read doesn't have to me executable or something

Comment: But surely it's useless trying to count the comments in a source code of a different language, or a C source which contains syntax errors??

Comment: As I said - it doesn't matter if the source is executable or not. Just have to count the comments if there are such.

Comment: Note that a compiler-level comprehension of comments requires you to understand strings and character constants and backslash-newline combinations (and nominally trigraphs too).  The code shown handles none of those.  Mostly that doesn't matter; when did you last see 'real' C code that had a slash, backslash, newline, star sequence to start a comment?  Backslash-newline after a `//` comment start continues the 'single line' comment onto the next line, though.

Comment: @Alex it matters if you find an unmatched comment termination `*/`. How many comments does that make? 0 or 1? And how many preceding `//` style comments was it supposed to "comment-out"?

Comment: Well 0 but we are newbies here. It's not expected from us to handle these situations. Let's say we are expected to read a simple file with a couple of comments in it. Nothing else. There won't be "// blah blah" or unclosed multi-line comments.

Comment: In that case you should have written it yourself instead of whipping another's work. "I found it on the internet but I can't make it answer my homework".

Comment: The problem is that the professor will talk about manipulating files next month and we have to finish the task by the end of next week. I made it to fit my task but don't actually understand how the enums work here. So I wanted a help to make an alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

Since enum is equivalent to a bunch of #define 's, you can replace this part of the code:

```
enum states {
    TEXT, 
    SAW_SLASH, 
    SAW_STAR, 
    SINGLE_COMMENT, 
    MULTI_COMMENT
} state = TEXT;
```

with:

```
#define TEXT           0
#define SAW_SLASH      1
#define SAW_STAR       2
#define SINGLE_COMMENT 3
#define MULTI_COMMENT  4

int state = TEXT;
```